# Replace commas with spaces ? Fisher-Yates randomization

Tags: random, shuffle, randomized-algorithm, fisher-yates-shuffle

Thanks to [@axtck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12378923/axtck) for the help for the Fisher Yates randomization, he helped me to change number into words here :

[Since the shuffle functions shuffle the arrays indexes, you can just shuffle the array the same way you did but add name strings in the array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67826149/replace-numbers-with-words-fisher-yates-randomization)

The code is now showing a string of words with commas as separation between the words, its working well!

Now I want to replace commas, with spaces (example : Histoire Chien Koala Arbre Italique Lampadaire Docteur Boulet Maison Forge Gagnant Ennui)

Can somebody help me to change these commas with blank spaces?

Thanks

```js
   // replace numbers with names   
const inputArray = ["Arbre", "Boulet", "Chien", "Docteur", "Ennui", "Forge", "Gagnant", "Histoire", "Italique", "Koala", "Lampadaire", "Maison"];


//define Fisher-Yates shuffle
const fisherShuffle = function(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue,
    randomIndex;

  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  document.getElementById("fyresults").append(array.toString());
};

fisherShuffle(inputArray);
```

```html
<p><span id="fyresults"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `toString()` on an array will return the string representation of the array which is *item1,item2,...*.

If you want to join the array in another way, you can use array method `join()`, it takes a separator string, which in your case would be a space `join(" ")`.

Some examples:

```js
const testArr = ["first", "second", "..."]; // example array

const arrString = testArr.toString(); // calling toString() on it
const arrJoinedX = testArr.join("X"); // joining by X
const arrJoinedSpace = testArr.join(" "); // joining by space

// logging
console.log("Array:", testArr);
console.log("Array toString():", arrString);
console.log("Array joined with X:", arrJoinedX);
console.log("Array joined with space:", arrJoinedSpace);
```

So to apply this to your example, you can do:

```js
// replace numbers with names   
const inputArray = ["Arbre", "Boulet", "Chien", "Docteur", "Ennui", "Forge", "Gagnant", "Histoire", "Italique", "Koala", "Lampadaire", "Maison"];


//define Fisher-Yates shuffle
const fisherShuffle = function(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue,
    randomIndex;

  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  
  const joinedBySpace = array.join(" "); // join by space
  document.getElementById("fyresults").append(joinedBySpace); // append to element
};

fisherShuffle(inputArray);
```

```html
<p><span id="fyresults"></span></p>
```